# NDK build error with cygwin

Tags: android, cygwin, tesseract

i am tying to build a tesseract project to use as a library for my project. I am getting this error with cygwin when trying to build on windows 7 with User Account Controls turned off.

```
$ /cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r8/ndk-build
SharedLibrary  : liblept.so
C:/android-ndk-r8/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libgnustl_static.a: No such file: Permission denied
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
/cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r8/build/core/build-binary.mk:369: recipe for target `obj/local/armeabi/liblept.so' failed
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/liblept.so] Error 1
```

please let me know what i should do to build the project.

Comment: Have you investigated why you're getting the `Permission denied` as per `C:/android-ndk-r8/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libgnustl_static.a: No such file: Permission denied` <----

Comment: @t0mm13b: i googled it and I found answers related to switching off UAC. i did that but i still get the same error.

Comment: **No such file** in relation to `libgnustl_static.so` - look again!

Comment: @t0mm13b: i searched the android-ndk-r8 folder and i could not find the `libgnustl_static.so file` so where should i look for this file?

Comment: Sorry for not getting back to you, heads up! I searched for `libgnustl_static` and the search yielded `libgnustl_static.a` instead across `c:\android\android-ndk-r8b\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.4.3\libs` and `c:\android\android-ndk-r8b\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.6\libs`. So my guess is you're attempting to link a shared library instead of static?

Comment: What boggles my mind is this - and excuse my bluntness, but... you figured out how to install cygwin on your pc... just saying... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808161/compiling-tesseract-through-android-ndk?rq=1 and on the right hand side over there to see if there's any more pertinent info that might help you --->

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot of people have struggled with compiling tesseract under Windows, and Cygwin is normally suggested, however its often not necessary.

Have you tried looking at the [tess-two](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two) project on github? Its tesseract wrapped with some handy android classes, compiling a running is simply a case of :

1. git clone git://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two tess
2. cd tess
3. cd tess-two
4. ndk-build
5. android update project --path .
6. ant release

I've been able to compile the above on 3 windows7 machines, a mac, and ubuntu without any issues.

Comment: can you please compile the project and ssend it to me, I'm a win use and I'm getting the same error more and more.

Comment: @firasman I was just using the standard windows 7 terminal, I didn't use anything like Cygwin, it just worked (on several machines)

Answer (score 15):

Sorry It's my first time answering a question.
I was having a same issue as yours.
Then I solve it using cygwin bash with command: `$ chmod -R 777 /cygdrive/c/android/workspace`
`C:/Android/workspace` is my Eclipse work space.
Some one [here](http://forum.thegamecreators.com/?m=forum_view&t=194719&b=46) gave me the insight

Comment: yes man! it helped like a charm! Great thanks to you, I was googling for an hour to find solution!!!

Comment: Thanks, that problem was plaguing me for ages. This worked sweetly. I was having this issue constantly once I split my SDK/NDK project into an Android library project and two (free and paid) application projects referencing it.

Comment: This command is not recommanded, you give all rights to everyone. In my case, a cloud software locked a big file.so, while uploading it. Interrupt cloud synchronization and clean/rebuild your project.

Answer (score 0):

if you're developing under windows, go to the file, and change it's premissions to full control.

it will be in /obj dir